# Is it possible to add text inputs together into one variable?

Tags: pine-script

I was hoping someone could tell me if it is possible to add text inputs together into one variable in Pine script?

I have some smaller code from a larger project where I hope to add text inputs together into one variable for both security() and label.new() outputs.

i.e. -

```
'''

`//@version = 4
study(title="", shorttitle="")
resolutionString = input("Pair Resolution", type=resolution, defval="240")
e = input(title = "Exchange", type=string,defval="BINANCE:")
b = input(title = "Base", type=string,defval="BTC")
q = input(title = "Quote", type=string,defval="ETH")
s1  = security(symbol=tostring(e,q,b), resolutionString, close)
plot(s1, color=color.red, linewidth=2, title=p1)`

'''
```

Any help or input would be greatly appreciated, sorry if it is a NOOBISH question but for the life of me I can't work an answer out.

Regards,
Andrew

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate the input?

Comment: Yes I believe that is what I am trying to do. I basically want 1 input for an exchange, 1 input for the base currency and 4 different inputs for the quote currency to combine into the necessary security/symbols for 4 outputs/plots and also to populate corresponding labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate strings with `+`

This will work:

```
//@version = 4
study(title="", shorttitle="")

resolutionString    = input(title = "Pair Resolution",  type=input.resolution,  defval = "240")
e                   = input(title = "Exchange",         type=input.string,      defval = "BINANCE:")
b                   = input(title = "Base",             type=input.string,      defval = "ETH")
q                   = input(title = "Quote",            type=input.string,      defval = "BTC")

mysymbol = e + b + q

s1  = security(mysymbol, resolutionString, close)
p1  = "myPlotTitle"

plot(s1, color=color.red, linewidth=2, title=p1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Bjorn Mistiaen, this is exactly what I needed. You and Popsyjunior are awesome.